# Flask: Is there any universal way to import heterogenous shapefiles (with different attributes) to PostGIS?

Tags: python, postgis, flask

Currently, I'm creating a geoportal based on Flask framework.
Before, I only needed to store homogenous shapefiles, all compatible with one known attribute structure. To create a table in PostGIS to store a particular shapefile's geometries, I created a class in a Flask app file, where I defined known attribute columns, e.g.:

```
class ModelSHP(base):   
    __tablename__ = 'model_shps'

    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    ADM2_PCODE = Column(String)
    ADM2_EN = Column(String)
    RMSE_05 = Column(Float)
    MASE_05 = Column(Float)
    geom = Column(Geometry('MULTIPOLYGON', srid=4326))
```

Now I want to store many heterogenous shapefiles (with different attributes),
so is there any universal way to import them as tables of geometries, without need to define separate classes for each particular shapefile based on their attributes?

Maybe storing attributes as PostGIS table columns isn't a good practice?

Comment: Keep in mind that PostgreSQL is the database that table columns, not PostGIS. PostGIS stores the geometry, and supports multiple geometry types in a single table, but it's generally not wise to mix point/line/polygon data in a single table. In fact, it's generally unwise to attempt to store many unlike things in a single table (it violates the fundamentals of relational theory, and will only cause problems down the road) -- If you have unalike features, they should be stored in different containers.

Comment: @Vince  So, will it be okay to store different shapefiles of same geometry type in one table? And save their attributes, which may be different for each new shapefile, in one special column as a python dictionary for example

Comment: No. Best practice is to to use tables to store like things. It's okay to merge counties from different states, but not to merge counties and parcels, even if they are both polygons. I once worked a project where some academic tried to store all the government's data in one table, and it failed initial design review and the project was cancelled (it was an embarrassment for the prime contractor, too).